# Show that $\{f_n(x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesnt converge in M.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}$ and $g(x)=\Bigg\{\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & x=0 \\
      \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2} & x \neq 0 \\
\end{array} $

You can assume that g is continuous and bounded with maximum in 0. Let M be the metric space $M=(B(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||_u)$

$B(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is the set of bounded functions $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

1. Show that $\{f_n(x) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesnt converge in M.
2. Show that $\{g \circ f_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in M.

After trying for the better part of 2 hours to come up with an approach to get started, I've found myself incapable. Any hints, solutions or general approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess $\|\|_u$ id the uniform norm. For 1): assuming $(f_n)$ converges, what would be its limit $f$? Then compute $\|f_n-f\|_u$, and get a contradiction. For 2): don't bother proving this, it's false. Are you sure you didn't make a typo?

Comment: The metric space $M$ is complete (can you show it?). A way to go about it may be to show that the sequence in $(1)$ is not Cauchy and the sequence in $(2)$ is (all with respect to ${\lVert \cdot \rVert}_u$).